# How to make Authlogic sessions work for all subdomains

Tags: subdomain, authlogic

When a user logs into my site at `example.com`, I want him to be logged in when he visits `something.example.com`. How can I accomplish this? (I'm using subdomain-fu if relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to add this to `production.rb`:

```
if config.action_controller.session
  config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.your-site.com'
else
  config.action_controller.session = { :domain => '.your-site.com' }
end
```

I still can't get it to work in development with `localhost:3000`, but whatever

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can, just add following lines into /etc/hosts after "127.0.0.1 localhost"

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.com
127.0.0.1 sub.localhost.com
```

Then edit your environments/development.rb and add

```
config.action_controller.session = { :domain => '.localhost.com' }
```

From now on use http://localhost.com:3000 or the same but with sub-domain to access your app locally.

[update] oops, it was the answer to Horace Loeb

Answer (score 1):

For Rails3 the code above will raise `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `session=' for ActionController::Base:Class
```

So, for Rails3 you should not change you environment config but should set your `app/config/initializers/session_store.rb` to look like:

```
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store,
    {:key => '_your_namespace_session', :domain => '.yourdomain.com'}
```

Also after changing the initializer you'll need to restart a webserver in order to apply the initializer.

Notice, that users who were logged in before code update won't be able to logout after that because the default logout action which is looking something like:

```
destroy
  current_user_session.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "You have been logged out"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

is not sufficient - it doesn't delete `user_credentials` cookie set for a non-wildcard domain `yourdomain.com` by default. So you should add `cookies.delete :user_credentials` to the destroy action so it will look like this:

```
destroy
  current_user_session.destroy
  cookies.delete :user_credentials
  flash[:notice] = "You have been logged out"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

And that's odd but it should be added after destroying user session despite of       `cookies[:user_credentials].is_nil? == true` at this point. Also there is a problem that after a user logouts and then logins having `cookies.delete :user_credentials` in the `destroy` action also makes users to be unable to logout and it should be removed. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Update. Finally I came up to this - I added a boolean flag to User model via migration:

```
class AddReloginedToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :relogined, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

and changed the destroy action this way:

```
def destroy
  current_user_session.destroy
  if !current_user.relogined
    current_user.relogined = true
    current_user.save
    cookies.delete(:user_credentials)
  end
  session = nil
  flash[:notice] = "You have been logged out"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Now everything works as expected although that's not a very beautiful solution. I'll be glad if anyone provides something smarter.